# JAXBContext implementation configuration not picked up

Tags: java, jaxb, java-ee-7, payara

I am looking for a way to refactor my JAXBContext implementation configuration from [a `jaxb.properties` file in every package containing an entity] to [a single configuration file].

In "Discovery of JAXB implementation"-section in the [`JAXBContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html)-documentation i find

> When one of the newInstance methods is called, a JAXB implementation is discovered by the following steps.
>   ...
>   3. Look for /META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext file in the associated classloader. This file follows the standard service descriptor convention, and if such a file exists, its content is assumed to be the provider factory class. This phase of the look up is for automatic discovery. It allows users to just put a JAXB implementation in a classpath and use it without any furhter configuration.

This does work in my unit tests, but not when i deploy the application on Payara 4.174.

When using the following file I get the following implementation from `JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz)`: `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext@15e2f4b5`

```bash
# src/main/resources/org/example/packagecontainingentity/jaxb.properties
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Yet, when I remove the `jaxb.properties` and rely on the following file I get the following implementation: `bundle://239.0:1/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.class`

```bash
# src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

I cannot find other instances of the `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` in my project (in dependencies for example) and I do not have a `JAXB_CONTEXT_FACTORY` JVM setting.

The `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` is actually in the war and I tried the following locations:

```
/META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext 
/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
```

What am I missing here? Do I not understand the configuration system or am I encountering some Payara bug?